# Aligning data from PostgreSQL and ArcGIS Desktop in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, postgresql, coordinate-system, utm

I am pretty new to ArcGIS and QGIS. I have loaded some geometry data in QGIS from my postgres database, then I have also loaded the same data in ArcGIS. Then from ArcGIS i have created a shapefile containing part of the data loaded from the database.

Now my problem is that when I load the shapefile containing part of the whole geometry data in QGIS , they are not being displyed on top of each other. Instead they are displayed both totally in different locations.

Now my data from postgres is set to 4326 and my data created in ArcGIS is set to wgs1984 UTM 33N.

**I have uploaded these two images to explain more myself. I would like that in QGIS will appear that the blue rectangle will be on its twin rectangle. NOT ON ANOTHER PART**

[image]

Comment: Just create the Shapefile in 4326 too. Or is your question how to do exactly that?

Comment: but from arcgis it asks for the utm zone location rather then just 4326 like in postgres. it might be that i am doing somehting wrong. And what is exactly the differencxe between 4326 and the UTM ZONE location?

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: 4326 = WGS 1984 = lat/lon geographical coordinates (degrees). This is NOT the same as UTM. UTM is a projected coordinate system.

Comment: do you know how i can edit the projection from qgis?. because if so i think it is a proejction problem.

Comment: In ArcMap, open data frame properties (right click Layers in the TOC) and select the coordinate system tab. Look at the list of coordinate systems in the map and check that each layer has a defined coordinate system and what are they?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the shapefiles to line up then select a project Coordinate Reference System by going to **Settings > Project Properties**. From [Spatialthoughts blog](http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/04/tutorial-working-with-projections-in.html):

> Check the box next to ‘Enable ‘on the fly’ CRS transformation’. Next
>   select the ‘common’ projection that all the current and subsequent
>   layers would be automatically reprojected to. We would keep that as
>   WGS84. Click OK.

[image]

Right click on either of your layers and click **Zoom to Layer Extent**. They should line up now.

Comment: I have done that and still the same. I am not sure if this helps to solve the problem but my scale of one layer when i do zoom to layer extent is: 1:12164152 and the other is 1:387. could it be something from this??

Comment: Open a new ArcMap. Add your shapefile to ArcMap. 1) move the mouse - tell what coordinates are shown in the status line of ArcMap. 2) open the properties of the layer. what coordinate system is shown on the coordinate system tab?

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS, go to Layer Properties of the "wrong" layer and change the projection to 4326. If the layers align, it tells us that the Shapefile was wrongly exported from ArcGIS.